# While in Mysql Only Pulls the last result?

Tags: php, html, mysql, chat, message

I got this simple script , unfortunately It has a issue , its only pulling the last result of the table called site where its supposed to replace badwords/bannedwords/smiles , here's the system That I've made, thanks!

```
<?php
$select=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chat ORDER BY id DESC");
while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($select)) {
  $mid=$rows['id'];
  $name=$rows['name'];
  $text=$rows['message'];
  $date=$rows['date'];

  $sitechoose = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM site");
  while($change = mysql_fetch_assoc($sitechoose)){
    $o =  array($change['original'],);
    $r =  array($change['changed'],);
    $messages = str_replace($o, $r, $text);
  }
  echo "<div class='chat-content'>
        <div class='background chat-title'>
          <a href='user.php?id=".$name."'>
             <span class='user-name user-group-".$power."'>".$name."</span>
          </a>
          <div class='chat-date float-r'>
            <time datetime='2014-12-06T16:56:36+00:00'>".$date."</time>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='chat-message'>".$messages."</div>
       </div>";
 } 
?>
```

It is only pulling out the last result inserted in the site table , I wonder why and how can I fix it?

Comment: Put the echo in the loop

Comment: where? What do you mean? Sorry Im not familiar with loops in an echo , can you explain please?

Comment: Posted the answer below

Comment: Please stop using mysql_query , use PDO !

Comment: I don't know how to use PDO

Comment: use mysqli or use pdo(they are database wrappers). if you use pdo its easier to flex your sql queries to mutiple database systems. Dont use mysql database wrapper its deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking what the problem was we finally found it :)

```
<?php

    $select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chat ORDER BY id DESC");

    while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($select)) {
        $mid=$rows['id'];
        $name=$rows['name'];
        $text=$rows['message'];
        $date=$rows['date'];

        $sitechoose = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM site");

        while($change = mysql_fetch_assoc($sitechoose)) {
            $o = $change['original'];
            $r = $change['changed'];
            $text = str_replace($o, $r, $text);
        }

        echo "<div class='chat-content'><div class='background chat-title'><a href='user.php?id=".$name."'><span class='user-name user-group-".$power."'>".$name."</span></a><div class='chat-date float-r'><time datetime='2014-12-06T16:56:36+00:00'>".$date."</time></div></div><div class='chat-message'>".$text."</div></div>";
    } 

 ?>
```

Comment: IT works but posts the message itself about 12 times , any idea?

Comment: INstead of displaying 12 messages it displays 144 messages .

Comment: Messages repeat themselves

Comment: That is probably because you got a loop in a loop here. I'll edit my main post

Comment: so the messages themselves do they go after or before?

Comment: The second code-block has the answer you are probably looking for, copy - paste it and look at the result :)

Comment: That didn't fix it either

Comment: There are 12 records and for each record is being copied 18 times because there are 18 replace in table site

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71173/discussion-between-jordy-and-mex).

Comment: Thankyou Soo Much, It Worked , I have no words to say , may I have your contact incase Ill post some question like this one sense Im working on this site for ages and I want to perfection it , thanks again !

Comment: You may always contact me on jordy-12345@hotmail.nl